# Python split text files by paragraph to csv

Tags: python, csv, text, split, paragraph

I have several text files that I would like to split by paragraph and transpose to a csv file. Each paragraph in my text files is separated by one empty line, and some long paragraphs have several lines. Here is an example of a text file:

"Hello world!

Blabla

(empty line)

This is the 2nd paragraph.
Here is more text

and this is a very long paragraph."

And I would like to obtain the following csv file:

| filename | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1.txt | Hello world! Blabla |
| 1.txt | This is the 2nd paragrah. Here is more text and this is a very long paragraph. |

This is the code that I have so far, but it only provides me one row: "1.text, [""Hello world!"", ""This is the 2nd paragraph. Here is more text. \nand this is a very long paragraph""]":

```
import os, csv
os.chdir('path where I have text files')
from pathlib import Path
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf-16") as out_file:
    csv_out = csv.writer(out_file)
    csv_out.writerow(['filename', 'Content'])
    for fileName in Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
        csv_out.writerow([str(fileName),open(str(fileName.absolute())).read().strip().split("\n\n")])
```

Comment: what did you mean by `paragraph`? new line? What the output that you got from the current code?

Comment: Rather than simply report "it doesn't work", please always explain what results you get vs. what you expect.

Comment: Please add details why you would read them in pandas `dataframe`. You may add pre-processing step to remove multiple consecutive `(\n){1,}` with a single `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you define the new paragraph with `\n\n` e.g.

> `Hello world!\n\nThis is the 2nd paragraph. Here is more text.`

So, you need to split the content by `.split('\n\n')` and then write them line by line.

Use the code below and update the path to your own:

```
import csv, os, sys
import glob

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf-16") as out_file:
    csv_out = csv.writer(out_file)
    csv_out.writerow(['filename', 'Content'])
    for text_file in glob.iglob('*.txt'):
        with open(text_file, 'r') as txt:
            for line in txt.read().split('\n\n'):
                csv_out.writerow([text_file, line])
```

and this is the output that you expect:

> ```
> filename,Content
> 1.txt,Hello world!
> 1.txt,This is the 2nd paragrah. Here is more text.
> 2.txt,Hello world! from 2.txt
> 2.txt,This is the 2nd paragrah. Here is more text. from 2.txt
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It works well with one problem. When I have long paragraphs (text with more than one line), the line continues in another row. I obtain: "1.txt, This is the 2nd paragraph. Here is more text". In another row "the text is very long"

Comment: can you show me the example of the content inside the text file? I need to see the format.

Comment: I edited my post to improve the example of my text file. Thank you

Comment: @MGFern if text has `\n` then it will display in next row in file, or in next line on screen. But it doesn't have to means that it keep it as new row in table - it still can be part of previous row in table. And if you don't want it next line on screen then `.replace("\n", " ")`

Comment: Instead of `\n\n` use `(\n){1,}`

Comment: furas, if I do `.replace("\n", " ")` to all text files in the folder, I obtain one paragraph in the text file. I am not able to understand which sentences belong to different paragraphs. Swarnkar Rajesh, doing `(\n){1,}` gives me each line in a different row.